# Parse value to None in ndb custom property

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have a custom ndb property subclass which should parse an empty string to None. When I return None in the _validate function, the None value is ignored and the empty string is still used.
Can I somehow cast input values to None?

```
class BooleanProperty(ndb.BooleanProperty):
    def _validate(self, value):
        v = unicode(value).lower()
        # '' should be casted to None somehow.
        if v == '':
            return None
        if v in ['1', 't', 'true', 'y', 'yes']:
            return True
        if v in ['0', 'f', 'false', 'n', 'no']:
            return False
        raise TypeError('Unable to parse value %r to a boolean value.' % value)
```

Comment: You need to show some code, you can store None in some properties. Are you subclassing the property correctly for instance.  You need to provide more information.

Comment: You are going about this the wrong way - See the docs for property subclasses - it says 

The _validate(), _to_base_type(), and _from_base_type() do not need to handle:

None: They will not be called with None (and if they return None, this means that the value does not need conversion).

Comment: Also to provide a custom validator you do not need to subclass the property just provide a validator when declaring the property.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?  A value of True, False and the ability to unset the bool ie reset back to None ?

Comment: I'm trying to parse the values directly from an api call. An empty string from the api parameters should set the value to None.

Comment: Did you read the docs "if they return None, this means that the value does not need conversion"  so the value returned from the _validate call will be ignored.

Comment: That's why I'm wondering if there is a workaround. Maybe by overriding another function. I can't really find it.

Comment: See the answer provided - use a computed property, or write your own version of a computed property - which will need more the validate method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My implementation overrides the _set_value method. This is not documented by the Appengine docs, but it works.

```
class MyBooleanProperty(ndb.BooleanProperty):
    def _set_value(self, entity, value):
        if value == '':
            value = None
        ndb.BooleanProperty._set_value(self, entity, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for something like *ndb.ComputedProperty*?

```
class YourBool(ndb.Model):
    my_input = StringProperty()
    val = ndb.ComputedProperty(
        lambda self: True if self.my_input in ["1","t","True","y","yes"] else False)
```